# How do I create a guest ftp user with SSH?

Tags: java, putty, virtual-server

I just got a virtual dedicated server at GoDaddy. I got the Simple Control Panel. There doesn't seem to be a way to create a guest ftp user through this control panel and I was told it must be created through SSH. I have a program called Putty which can log into the server via SSH. I'm familiar with logging in but does anyone know what the commands are to be used to create a guest ftp user and give them Read and Write access to a particular folder?

Please help.

I found the following steps when i was googling. But the PUTTY is throwing an error when i used USERADD command.

> To create FTP user through SSH you
>       would need to follow below mentioned
>       steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Login as root through SSH.
>
> 2. Next add the user account you want using the 'useradd' command
>
> useradd <username>
>
> 3. Now create a special group for that user.
>
> groupadd <groupname>
>
> 4. Now to add the user to the group
>
> gpasswd -a <username> <groupname>
>
> These commands are non-standard but
> available on most popular
> distributions. If not, then you can
> try editing /etc/group using your
> favorite text editor.
>
> 5. Change the group ownership of the special directory to that group.
>
> chgrp -R groupname
> /path/to/your/web/directory
>
> 6. Enable write permissions
>
> chmod -R g+rw
> /path/to/your/web/directory
> ```

Comment: what is the error thrown by useradd?

Comment: error message is "command not found"

Comment: There's also a Linux add user command named `adduser`.  I don't remember the exact difference (seems like one is pleasant to work with and the other not).  My distro (Fedora) has both, but yours might only have the one.

Comment: if you have no adduser either, you can use the traditional way your grandfather used: 1. add a line for the user to /etc/passwd 2. add a line to /etc/shadow 3. create the user home directory 4. change owner and group to the home directory and 5. define a password using passwd command.